# PostgreSQL Ordenar múltiples valores de teléfono en una sola instancia del cliente

Tags: postgresql

Tengo armada mi base de datos en postgres. Tengo varias tablas y sus atributos son:

```
persona [idPersona (PK),nombre,documento (unique),domicilio.]

telefonosPersonas [id (pk), telefono, personaCliente_id (FK a persona)]

vehiculo [idVehiculo (pk), dominio]

anomalias [codigo,Descripcion]

rtoanomalia [id(PK),planilla_id(FK a planilla),anomalia_id(FK a anomalias)]

planillarto [nroPlanilla,vehiculo_id(FK a vehiculo), operador_id (FK a persona)]
```

Mi objetivo es obtener todas las PLANILLAS donde el Vehículo tenga un código de anomalía = 100, hasta ahí todo va de maravilla.

Mi problema surge al querer mostrar no solo el dominio que cumple esa condición, sino también el nombre del operador asignado en la planilla (relacionado por operador_id) y TODOS sus números de teléfono que tenga almacenados (0-n).

Hasta ahora esto lo hago con el código del Backend, pero seguro se puede hacer desde el motor de la DB de forma más eficiente.

Intentando, pude lograr el siguiente query que funciona pero está mal, dado que el motor de la DB me obliga a meter el dominio dentro de groupBy, limitándome los resultados reales (Recuerdo que yo busco en si la PLANILLA que posee un vehículo asociado y dentro de la planilla cumple con esa condición de que la anomalía sea X)

```
select 
dominio,dsp.nombre,
string_agg(telefono, ', ') 
from "dataService_planillarto" 
LEFT JOIN "dataService_rtoanomalia" dSr on "dataService_planillarto"."nroPlanilla" = dSr."planilla_id"  
inner join "dataService_vehiculossistemarto" dSv on dSv."idVehiculo" = "dataService_planillarto".vehiculo_id 
inner join "dataService_persona" dSp on dSp."idPersona" = "dataService_planillarto".operador_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dataService_telefonospersonas" dSt on dSp."idPersona" = dSt."personaCliente_id" 
where dSr.anomalias_id = 100 
group by  dominio,nombre;
```

Con esta query, obtengo 423 filas. mientras que si aplico la más sencilla

```
select 
dominio, 
nombre from "dataService_planillarto" 
LEFT JOIN "dataService_rtoanomalia" dSr on "dataService_planillarto"."nroPlanilla" = dSr."planilla_id"  
inner join "dataService_vehiculossistemarto" dSv on dSv."idVehiculo" = "dataService_planillarto".vehiculo_id 
inner join "dataService_persona" dSp on dSp."idPersona" = "dataService_planillarto".operador_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dataService_telefonospersonas" dSt on dSp."idPersona" = dSt."personaCliente_id" 
where dSr.anomalias_id = 100;
```

obtengo 873 filas.

Claramente la consulta no es la correcta.

Por si sirve, no es necesario que todos los teléfonos se me coloquen en una sola columna (como hago con string_agg), podrían ponerse una al lado de otra pero no sé como hacerlo.

Dejo de paso los tipos de relaciones que hay entre las tablas principales:

```
vehiculos -- one to Many --> planillarto

persona -- one to Many --> planillarto

persona -- one to Many --> telefonosPersonas

persona --one to Many --> vehiculos
```

Mi objetivo, es que me devuelva algo así:

```
{'dominio','nombre','tel1','tel2',...'teln'}
{'ABC123','JUAN','123456789','16577743',...'88854'}
{'BBB444','PALBO','44456789','123456766',...'null'}
```

o, en última instancia:

```
{'dominio','nombre','telefonos'}

{'ABC123','JUAN','11664414, 125581921, 99958221'}
```

Como no me deja poner toda la data de prueba acá. Subí los SQL con al drive. les paso link.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda a todos.

[Drive Ejemplos SQL](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FsPVsxX3IeAy9--GC7uzjUVW0VOFsW2f?usp=sharing)